# Is it true that $\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t),h(t))=f'(g(t),h(t))g'(t)+f'(g(t),h(t))h'(t)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I want to solve the following question:

We want to find $\frac{du}{dt}$ where $u(x,y)=x^2y^3$ and $x=1+\sqrt{t}$ and $y=1-\sqrt{t}$.

I know we can just plug $x=1+\sqrt{t}$ and $y=1-\sqrt{t}$ in $u(x,y)$ to get $u(t)=(1+\sqrt{t})^2(1-\sqrt{t})^3$ and now we just derive with respect to $t$, but I want a more sophisticated approach and I don't really feel like opening all those brackets.

So I consulted with a friend, and he said that from chain rule we have: $\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t),h(t))=f'(g(t),h(t))g'(t)+f'(g(t),h(t))h'(t)$

I don't really see how chain rule implies that and I'd like some explanation for that, or another suggestion of how to solve the original question easily.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand partial derivatives of a function of two variables? Your friend is wrong, but the correct chain rule involves those partial derivatives of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is $$\frac d{dt}\left({f(g(t), h(t))}\right) = f_x(g,h)g'(t)+f_y(g,h)h'(t)$$ where the subscript means take the partial derivative with respect to that variable. if you have $$u = x^2y^3 \to u_x = 2xy^3, u_y=3x^2y^2\\x = 1 +\sqrt t, y =1-\sqrt t\to x'=\frac1{2\sqrt t}, y'=-\frac1{2\sqrt t}$$ finally, $$u' = u_xx'+u_yy'=2xy^3 \frac1{2\sqrt t} - 3x^2y^2\frac1{2\sqrt t}$$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule applicable here is

$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dt}&=(2xy^3)\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}-(3x^2y^2)\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\\\\
&=2(1+\sqrt{t})(1-\sqrt{t})^3\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}-3(1+\sqrt{t})^2(1-\sqrt{t})^2\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\\\\
&=\,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}(1-t)\left(2(1-\sqrt{t})^2-3(1-t)\right)
\end{align}$$